# Можно ли в Unity сделать так, чтобы коллайдер-триггер не реагировал на другой коллайдер-триггер?

Tags: unity3d

Пишу 2D шутер, и у меня пуля реализована через триггер и rigidbody, враг имеет rigidbody и 2 коллайдера - 1 это его тело, а 2 это его радиус атаки, тоже триггер, использую OnTriggerEnter2D для регистрации попаданий, все в целом было нормально, но как только я добавил врага с большим радиусом атаки, пули стали попадать в него по сути где бы он ни находился. Если указанное в вопросе нельзя сделать, то как вообще можно грамотно это реализовать? Можно конечно регистрировать попадание только когда пуля остановится, но это костыль уже, как мне кажется.

Comment: Решено, можно узнать с каким типом коллайдера столкнулся триггер - Collider2D.isTrigger

Answer (score 0):

попробуй на врага создать и накинуть новый слой, и также на пулю, один и тот же и сделай что бы они не сталкивались (Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D)
И там убирай галки (наведи курсором на галку, и покажет с чем она сталкивается, если - Enemy/Enemy(То как ты назвал слой) допустим то убирай галку, и все :)

Comment: так лучше всего реализовывать, меньше ресурсов тратится